# Convergence from spectrum of the Choi matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, positive-definite, quantum-mechanics

Suppose I have a linear operation of the form $T(C)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_i^m A_i C A_i$ for a set of $m$ symmetric $d \times d$ matrices $A_i$.

I construct Choi matrix below with $e_i$ referring to [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis)

$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
T(e_1 e_1^T) & T(e_1 e_2^T )& \ldots& T(e_1 e_d^T)\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots&\ldots\\
T(e_d e_1^T) & T(e_d e_2^T) & \ldots & T(e_d e_d^T)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Is it possible to tell if $T$ is contractive or [convergent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix) by looking at eigenvalues of $M$?

Note that entries of $M$ are rearrangement of entries of $T$ viewed as linear matrix acting on $\operatorname{vec}C$ ([Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism](https://mateusaraujo.info/2020/06/10/the-choi-jamiolkowski-isomorphism-youre-doing-it-right/))

$$
T=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\operatorname{vec}T(e_1 e_1^T)^T\\
\operatorname{vec}T(e_2 e_1^T)^T\\
\ldots \\
\operatorname{vec}T(e_d e_1^T)^T\\
\operatorname{vec}T(e_1 e_2^T)^T\\
\ldots \\
\operatorname{vec}T(e_d e_d^T)^T\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In my application, most eigenvalues of $M$ appear zero, while most eigenvalues of $T$ not-zero, so it seems that $M$ spectrum is easier to analyze.

Example:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Eigenvalues of $M$ are ${1, 1/2, 0, 0}$, while eigenvalues of $T$ are $\left\{\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right),-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right\}$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-choi-matrix-contractive.nb)

Comment: What do you mean by a 'convergent' linear application like $M?$

Comment: @GérardLetac https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix

Answer (score 2):

Since the $T$ and $M$ are basically a rearrangement of elements, their Frobenious norms are the same.

The eigenvalues satisfy

$$\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \lambda_i(M) = tr(M) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \|A_i\|_F^2. $$

Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \lambda_i(M)^2 = \|M\|_{F}^2\le (\frac{1}{m}\max_{i=1}^{m} \|A_i\|_{F}^2 )^2 $$

then the trivial bound is $\rho(T) \le \sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \lambda_i(M). $ It might not be quite useful if the RHS is greater than 1.

We might need additional information for a better estimate. For $T$ (which is also symmetric), the spectral radius of $T$ is smaller than its $\|T\|_1$, which is

$$\max_{k,l} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{s,t} |A_{i, k, s} A_{i, l, t}| = \max_{k,l} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m { \sum_{s=1}^d |A_{i, k, s}| \sum_{t=1}^d |A_{i, l, t}|} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \max_{k=1}^d\left| \sum_{s=1}^d |A_{i, k, s}| \right|^2 $$

therefore $$\rho(T)\le \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \max_{k=1}^d \left| \sum_{s=1}^d |A_{i, k, s}| \right|^2 = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \|A_i\|_1^2$$

When the matrices $A_i$ satisfy that $ \|A_i\|_1 \le \beta \|A_i\|_F$, for some $\beta < 1$ uniformly, then

$$\rho(T) \le \beta \sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \lambda_i(M). $$